# how to get data by name as well as its id in express route prameter, mongoose

Tags: node.js, api, express, rest

finding data by id, route parameter like this

url is : http://localhost:8000/products/60d1789867bc6624403ade6e

```
// getting a single product
router.get("/:id", async (req, res, next) => {
const id = req.params.id;
try {
    const result = await Product.findById(id);
    return res.json({
    result,
  });
  } catch (error) {
     return res.status(400).json({
     msg: "product not found",
     error: error,
  });
 }
});
```

but when I try to find by name
url : http://localhost:8000/products/product_name

```
// getting products by name
  router.get("/:name", async (req, res, next) => {
  const name = req.params.name;
  try {
      const result = await Product.find({ name: name });
      return res.json({
      result,
   });
   } catch (error) {
       return res.status(400).json({
       msg: "product not found",
       error: error,
    });
   }
  });
```

this block of code does not execute, url req goes to :id parameter

how to differenciate this

Comment: make two different get url because express gets http://localhost:8000/products/60d1789867bc6624403ade6e (ID route) first so it won't go into the product name route but if you want to get product name in the route then make two different get routes like http://localhost:8000/products/id/product_ID and http://localhost:8000/products/name/product_name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. For Express, both routes are same (giving the different name to variable doesn't work here).

You need to go with either one of the mentioned route and need to modifies the logic to find the `product` data.

```js
router.get("/:id_or_name", async (req, res, next) => {
```

Get the value of this `id_or_name` variable and check if it is the valid `ObjectId` is not using `mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid()`. If it is valid then execute the `.findById()` else go for `.find()` method.

```js
const id_or_name = req.params.id_or_name;

// ... code ...
if (mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(id_or_name)) {
  result = await Product.findById(id_or_name);
} else {
  result = await Product.find({ firstName: id_or_name });
}
// ... code ...
```